# Changing Activities Android Studio - Intent Error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to link to activities together with a button click. I keep getting an error displaying 
"ChangeActivityStudent() in MainActivity cannot be applied to (Androi.content.intent)"

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText userPassword;
    EditText userPin;
    EditText UserName;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView Title;
    Button GoBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserName = findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        userPassword = findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
        userPin = findViewById(R.id.userPin);
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        GoBtn = findViewById(R.id.GoBtn);


        checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        // called when check box is clicked

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //method called
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
        {
            userPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //when checkbox is check, userPin becomes visible
        }
        else
        {
            userPin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //otherwise userPin is invisible
        }

        GoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               ChangeActivityStudent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ChangeActivityStudent(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, StudentActivity.class);
       ChangeActivityStudent(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android, to start a new activity you don't call its constructor directly. This is done by the Android framework. Instead, you use `context.startActivity(intent)` (docs for this are [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))). So in this case:

```
private void changeActivityStudent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StudentActivity.class); 
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Since you are calling this from `MainActivity`which extends `Context` you can call this directly. Check out [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) for more information on how to start a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private void ChangeActivityStudent(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```